# Does m2Crypto 0.21 contains fips support?

Tags: m2crypto

I do see that there exists a fips test case tests/fips.py which reads /proc/sys/crypto/fips_enabled and this file contains a 0 at the moment. 
So, does this mean that there is fips support built into M2Crypto?
If yes, how do I enable fips from my python code?

Any comments please?

Answer (score 0):

You don't. FIPS mode shouldn't be enabled by user applications, but it is always systemwide (for more info see https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/137833 ... sorry, not sure about correct non-RH page, but I guess FIPS is used mostly by people who have access to R anyway). More or less ... see http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/1401val2012.htm#1758 for more.

So, yes, m2crypto contains functions for dealing with FIPS and that support is always on, but it has nothing to do with the state of FIPS in system.